# Como enviar JSON para o PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

Como envio este objeto por `ajax`, e leio no `php`?

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
//Aqui crio o objeto com os inputs 
var obj = new Object();
var objectsRadio = $('input:checked').map(function(i){
    obj.id_varejo = id_varejo;
    obj.id_pesquisa = idPesquisa;
    obj.id_pergunta = $(this).attr('name');
    obj.id_resposta = $(this).val();  

    return {
          id_varejo   : obj.id_varejo,
          id_pesquisa : obj.id_pesquisa,
          id_pergunta : obj.id_pergunta,
          id_resposta : obj.id_resposta
   };          
}).get();    

//Aqui sera o envio para php
var sql =  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'dadosPS.php?ps=saveResult',
    dataType : 'json',
    data: { 'dados' : objectsRadio },

    //data: jsonString,
    beforeSend: function () {
      //console.log("Before");
    },

    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // console.log("Success = " + data);
    },

    complete: function () {},

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        //console.log("Error"); 
    }
 });
```

Update do retorno, este eh o response do php

```
Array
(
[dados] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id_varejo] => 895
                [id_pesquisa] => 1
                [id_pergunta] => 1
                [id_resposta] => 3
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id_varejo] => 895
                [id_pesquisa] => 1
                [id_pergunta] => 2
                [id_resposta] => 8
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id_varejo] => 895
                [id_pesquisa] => 1
                [id_pergunta] => 3
                [id_resposta] => 11
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [id_varejo] => 895
                [id_pesquisa] => 1
                [id_pergunta] => 4
                [id_resposta] => 12
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [id_varejo] => 895
                [id_pesquisa] => 1
                [id_pergunta] => 5
                [id_resposta] => 13
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [id_varejo] => 895
                [id_pesquisa] => 1
                [id_pergunta] => 6
                [id_resposta] => 14
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [id_varejo] => 895
                [id_pesquisa] => 1
                [id_pergunta] => 7
                [id_resposta] => 16
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [id_varejo] => 895
                [id_pesquisa] => 1
                [id_pergunta] => 8
                [id_resposta] => 18
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [id_varejo] => 895
                [id_pesquisa] => 1
                [id_pergunta] => 9
                [id_resposta] => 23
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [id_varejo] => 895
                [id_pesquisa] => 1
                [id_pergunta] => 10
                [id_resposta] => 26
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [id_varejo] => 895
                [id_pesquisa] => 1
                [id_pergunta] => 11
                [id_resposta] => 29
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [id_varejo] => 895
                [id_pesquisa] => 1
                [id_pergunta] => 12
                [id_resposta] => 30
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [id_varejo] => 895
                [id_pesquisa] => 1
                [id_pergunta] => 13
                [id_resposta] => 31
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [id_varejo] => 895
                [id_pesquisa] => 1
                [id_pergunta] => 14
                [id_resposta] => 32
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [id_varejo] => 895
                [id_pesquisa] => 1
                [id_pergunta] => 15
                [id_resposta] => 33
            )

    )

)
```

no caso preciso inseri agora no banco mysql com esta estrutura de tabela

1. id (**pk,auto incremento**)
2. id_pesquisa
3. id_pergunta
4. id_respostaid_var

este seria o ponto final para que eu possa finalizar esta questão.

Comment: Você sabe que precisa usar AJAX, então já leu a documentação sobre? E o que tentou fazer após isso? Coloque seu código na pergunta.

Comment: use `$item = json_decode($json, true)`, depois pode fazer um foreach com algo como `echo $item[0]['id_pergunta']`

Comment: //Aqui crio o objeto com os inputs 
var obj = new Object();
var objectsRadio = $('input:checked').map(function(i) {
    obj.id_pergunta = $(this).attr('name');
    obj.id_resposta = $(this).val();
            
     return {
          id_pergunta : obj.id_pergunta,
          id_resposta : obj.id_resposta
       };       
   
}).get();

Comment: //Aqui sera o envio para php
       var sql =  $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: 'dadosPS.php?ps=saveResult',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data: [{ 'dados' : objectsRadio }],
                });

Comment: Carlos, logo abaixo da pergunta existe o botão [edit]. Use-o para inserir este código. Não esqueça de formatá-lo corretamente.

Comment: E o código PHP? Aliás, o que está acontecendo? Como identificou que este código não funciona? Aparece algum erro? Qual? O método HTTP não deveria ser `POST` ao invés de `GET`? Quais dados chegam no PHP? O que chega no JavaScript de volta?

Comment: Faça isso e veja o que retorna na requisição XHR do seu console:
`$array = json_decode($_POST['dados']); print_r($array); die();` Obs: tente enviar via post. GET com certeza vai dar problema.

Comment: O PHP recebe o array JS que vc enviar, você só precisa usar json_decode() para converter no formato de array.

Comment: Objs: 'dados' não precisa estar em formato string, pode usar assim: `... data: {dados:objectsRadio}`

Comment: o retorno do PHP, será sua saída echo do `json_decode()` que está dentro da variável de retorno: data do seu success, ou seja, faça um log: de `...success:function(data) { console.log(data) }`, não esquece de retirar o print_r() e dar echo no: `json_decode($_POST)`;

Comment: `Use $.ajax({  type: 'post', ...`

Comment: tentei ler o array com foreach mas so retorna erro... o que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um exemplo simples, seria assim...

```js
var objArr = []

for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++){
  objArr.push(i)
}

console.log(objArr)

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'SUA URL',
  data: objArr,
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data)
  }
})
```

Comment: No caso posso usar essa mesma logica para ler no php com foreach e dentro desse foreach realizar o insert?

Comment: @CarlosLopes Exatamente

Comment: Tem certeza se pode definir o objeto `ojbArr` com `let`? Ele existirá no escopo em `$.ajax`?

Comment: Foi apenas um exemplo, pois ia fazer sem jquery, com js puro. mas acabei colocando o jquery. mas o correto seria usar o var